# Alternative math evaluators in Python

Tags: library, python, programming, parser

#### What I am looking for

I am looking for a math evaluator in Python which supports variables and evaluation of expressions based on variable assignments.

#### What I have found

I found [python-expression-eval](https://github.com/Axiacore/py-expression-eval/issues/19) (also available on [PyPi](https://pypi.org/project/py_expression_eval/)) which seemed exactly what I was looking for. In fact, it makes you do the following things.

```
>>> parser = Parser()
>>> ev = parser.parse('x * x + 2*y + 5')
>>> ev.evaluate({'x': 3, 'y': 4})
22.0
```

Where that call of the `evaluate()` method means "evaluate the expression `x * x + 2*y + 5` in the case where `x` is 3 and `y` is 4.

#### But it is not maintained

Everything is perfect, except that as you can see from the [github page](https://github.com/Axiacore/py-expression-eval) the project seems not maintained much. There are only two "recent" changes, one five months ago and one five months ago, but they are both very small and one of the two is just on the `README` file. The [issues](https://github.com/Axiacore/py-expression-eval/issues) opened by the users are not closed since November 2017 and there are no replies by the authors, not even for some issues opened in 2016.

The bugs reported by the users are not fixed, and I have found another important bug which prevents me from debugging my own code. In particular I get a `cannot concatenate str and float` error when I call the `toString()` method if there are *negative* numbers in the math expression (e.g. `'-2 + x'`). This prevents me from using `toString()` to check if an expression has been parsed correctly.

#### Then I ask:

do you know any well-maintained library which is alternative to `python-expression-eval`?

Comment: You may want to add a more challenging example. For yours you do not need a library at all: `eval('x * x + 2*y + 5', {"x":3,"y":4}` does the job.

Comment: I will edit the question soon with a more challenging example I already have in mind (and I will delete this comment of mine afterwards).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[SymPy](http://sympy.org/) is able to do what you are asking for (and much more):

```
from sympy import sympify
from sympy.abc import x,y

expr = sympify('x * x + 2*y + 5')
expr.subs({ x:3, y:4 })
```

Note that this is only one of several ways to do what you ask for in SymPy.

It is not only under [active development](https://github.com/sympy/sympy) but the backbone of other Python modules.
Hence there is a great interest in keeping it maintained, backwards-compatible, and robust.